# Webpack 2 loaders declared in reverse?

Tags: webpack

When using webpack 2, why is it that loaders need to be added for the "use:" key in reverse order? Why not list each loader from first to last, left to right? Is there a reason?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like a convention that could just as easily be the other way to match the convention of execution order matching source order, but the reason it uses this "reverse" order is because it's not using a sequential model, but a nested one. Like an onion, the top/left items wrap the lower/right items.

The reason is that they are essentially function calls, so this:

```
rules: {
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader'
  ]
}
```

doesn't mean "Do the CSS Loader, then the Style Loader" and is just declared backwards. Instead, it's essentially equivalent to `style-loader(css-loader())`, so as you go down the list, each subsequent loader is a nested function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does, it just seems confusing for the "consumer" until that's been explained. Thanks greatly for the explanation. 

Comment: Yeah, I had to dig a bit to find the answer. In fact, I found your question because I had the same one! I should probably submit a documentation PR to clarify this.